# How to change number of particles in gmapping package?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, gmapping, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to ask is this is the correct coding to change the number of particles of the gmapping package in launch file?

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="configuration_basename" default="turtlebot3_lds_2d.lua"/>
  <arg name="set_base_frame" default="base_footprint"/>
  <arg name="set_odom_frame" default="odom"/>
  <arg name="set_map_frame"  default="map"/>

  <!-- Gmapping -->
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="turtlebot3_slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg set_base_frame)"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg set_odom_frame)"/>
    <param name="map_frame"  value="$(arg set_map_frame)"/>
    <param name="particles"  value="100"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/config/gmapping_params.yaml" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

Im adding  `<param name="particles"  value="100"/>` in the launch file as above. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401315/how-to-change-number-of-particles-in-gmapping-package?/) by [MirulJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/87165/mirulj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best place would be the file:

> $(find
> turtlebot3_slam)/config/gmapping_params.yaml

Since the line:

```
<rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/config/gmapping_params.yaml" />
```

Is going to overwrite any ros parameters that you have defined before.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0